# ValueError: the truth value of an array in HOG detection script python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, raspberry-pi, valueerror

I'm writing a full body detection script with automatic img safe when body is detected via webcam (logitech c170) using a RaspberryPi3, Opencv3 and Python3.5

This is what I have so far

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os


def inside(r, q):
    rx, ry, rw, rh = r
    qx, qy, qw, qh = q
    return rx > qx and ry > qy and rx + rw < qx + qw and ry + rh < qy + qh


def draw_detections(img, rects, thickness = 1):
    for x, y, w, h in rects:

        pad_w, pad_h = int(0.15*w), int(0.05*h)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x+pad_w, y+pad_h), (x+w-pad_w, y+h-pad_h), (0, 255, 0), thickness)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    num = 0
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    hog.setSVMDetector( cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector() )
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    previously_found = False

    while True:
        _,frame=cap.read()
        found,w=hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8), padding=(32,32), scale=1.05)
        if all(found) and not previously_found:
            previously_found = True
            cv2.imwrite('/home/pi/jebenter/'+'opencv'+str(num)+'.jpg',frame)
            num = num+1
        elif not all(found):
            previously_found = False

        draw_detections(frame,found)
        cv2.imshow('feed',frame)
        ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
        if ch == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When executed I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peopledetectF.py, line 30, in <module>
    if all(found) and not previously_found:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried replacing the `all` with `any`, didn't work. I read something about using `&` and `*` instead of `and` `or`

But do not really know how to apply this. Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`found` is a NumPy array. The traceback tells you the solution.

Therefore, change:

```
if all(found) and not previously_found:
```

to:

```
if found.all() and not previously_found:
```

Comment: Tried but I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peopledetectF.py", line 30, in <module>
    if found.all() and not previously_found:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'`

Comment: Check the content of `found`.  It is a tuple that contains a NumPy array. So maybe `found[0].all()` works.

Comment: Tried but I'm now getting this. I just started working with python a week ago, I'm sorry if I'm stating obvious problems but I'm a bit lost (and on 
a deadline..) `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peopledetectF.py", line 30, in <module>
    if found[0].all() and not previously_found:
IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: Does not make sense to me. Either the tuple is empty, than there is no such error message abou t`all`, or it contains a NumPy array, than it should be index-able.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `all(found)`, why don't you check `len(found)`? That should tell you the number of rectangles that contain the object you are trying to detect.

```
if len(found) == 0:
   print "no detections"
else:
   print str(len(found)) + " detections(s) found"
```

Comment: Awesome. Hopefully you made your deadline